# Parse data from Morningstar Direct to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, finance

I have to put together a report every quarter using data pulled off of Morningstar Direct. I have to automate the whole process, or at least parts of it. We have put this report together for the last two quarters, and we use the same format each time. So, we already have the general templates for the report - now I'm just looking for a way to pull the data from Morningstar and putting into the templates correctly.

Does anyone have any general idea where I should start?

```
  A            B            C           D           E        F
Group         Name        Weight      Gross        Net     Contribution
Equity                      25%        10%          8%       .25
              IBM           5%         15%         12%    
              AAPL          7%         23%         18%
Fixed Income                25%        5%           4%       .17
            10 Yr Bond      10%        7%           5%
Emerging Mrkts
```

And it goes on breaking things into more groups, and there are many more holdings within each group.

What I want it to do is search until it finds "Equity", for example, and then go over one row, grab the name of the position, its weight, and its net return, and do that for each holding in Equity. The for it to do the same thing in Fixed Income, and on and on - selecting the names, weights, and nets for each holding. Then copy and pasting them into another workbook.

Anyway that is possible?

Comment: Are you looking for VBA to pull the data from the website itself? Or do you already have the data and just need to format it?

Comment: Is Morning-Star a program? A website? Does it have a file format or an API?

Comment: Morningstar Direct is a program itself on my computer. It comes with the ability to export data sets I need into excel (it opens its own workbook), but there is a lot of superfluous data along with the stuff I actually need - and the formatting is awful, its very raw. So, I can pull the data from Morningstar easily enough - but then I need to move it into its own workbook and reformat it, as well as delete all the superflous data.
                                        
Morningstar Direct has its own API as well, but that is useless.

Comment: re:¹ *'its very raw'* - This is very best thing that you could have. re:² *'Morningstar Direct has its own API'* - This is the second best thing you could have. All you require is someone willing to sign an NDA that can work alongside you with your account and password to develop a direct pull from Morningstar Direct using their API.

Comment: Clarified my problem  - more info is in the "answer" section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to parse your information. By using left(), right(), and mid() you can select the good data and ignore the superfluous. You could separate the data in one cell into multiple cells in the desired format.

```
A                  B  
Name               Address  
John Q. Public     123 My Street, City, State, Zip

E (First Name)          F (Middle Initial) (extra work to program missing data)  
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))  =MID(A2,LEN(E2)+1,FIND(" ",MID(A2,LEN(E2)-1,99)))

G (Last Name)                      H (City)  
=MID(A2,(LEN(E2)+LEN(F2)+2),99)    =MID(B2,LEN(H2)+2,FIND(",",MID(B2,LEN(H2)+2,99))-1)

I (State)  
=MID(B2,(LEN(I2)+LEN(H2)+4),FIND(",",MID(B2,(LEN(I2)+LEN(H2)+4),99))-1)

J (Zip Code)
=MID(B2,(LEN(H2)+LEN(I2)+LEN(J2)+6),99)
```

This code will parse the name in the cell A2 and address in cell B2 into separate fields. 
Similar cuts should allow you to get rid of the unwanted data.

==================================================================
7/8/2015

Your data seems to be your desired output. If so, please provide sanitized input data for comparison. You probably need to loop through your input to find the groups. When the group changes, prepare the summary figures.

Comment: Responded to you in the answer field. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer; this is additional information meant to clarify the question. Please don't post such material as an answer. Just edit your original question by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31253488/edit) link below it.